# replace text in Sharepoint designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-online, workflow-activity

I have a List with a item of multistring value with length greater than 255.e.g 500 characters.

The workflow needs to run on every change and not manually.

I  am using SharePoint 2013 online version and not on premises.

**Issue**
Need to find and replace a string and replace it with another string.

**Option1**
If I use a string local variable to store the char after 255 is truncated.
I can use the replace action SharePoint 2013 to replace the string but I need to be able to get the whole string without being truncated.

**Option2**
Can I Use dictionary variable.
When I used a dictionary the workflow was getting suspended. Can I use the dictionary action to store the list item which is greater than 255 . 
Does Dictionary have the same limitation of the string 255

**Option3**
The initial initiation parameters has a multistring option . 
When I used it to store the value of the List Item. The workflow seemed to be stuck as it did not do anything but remaining in the started state forever.
I had set the default value of the parameters.

Is it possible to use the Initial parameters in a workflow which needs to run automatically.

**Option 4**
Is it possible to use the Workflow actions pack from Plumsail to achieve this functionality. 
It has a split action. Can I use the Split functionality to achieve this.
Is there a sample example or any posts.

There should definitely another way to replace text with length greater than 255 as it sounds academic.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why multi line init parameter is not working for you.

Also Plumsail `Split String` action you can use. After splitting you will get a `Dictionary` object. Just iterate and replace the string value as required.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Whenever I used multi line init parameters  the workflow always never completed. Does multi line init parameter work when the workflow is  triggered when changed and not manual. Can the dictionary split the string into string values . How do i get the value from it.  The method i used was Get the count of the dictionary and then add a for loop and in the for loop . I added the get the dictionary item using the get the item from dictionary but the  workflow always ended in suspended state.   Is there any good article or  instructions that  I can follow.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create dynamic email message without replace string inside designer workflow 2013.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Please expand your answer to give a bit more information, otherwise you risk being downvoted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using a SP 2013 workflow, this site says there is an action "Replace Substring in String" that you could use:

http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/sharepoint-2013/sharepoint-designer-workflow-string-actions.htm

You would use it like `Replace me with you in Me are doing well`.

But your workflow would have to be a 2013 workflow to have that action.  If it is and you see it, you can use it and ignore the rest of my post.

If you aren't using a 2013 workflow, it will not give you the action, above - even if your site is on 2013 (I have a 2013 site and I've checked).  So you would create a 2013 workflow on your list from the start and you should have the action.  From here, you can either start re-writing your workflow from scratch if you don't have many lines to re-create, or if you do, keep reading.

**To import your workflow into your new 2013 workflow:**

- Export both the source (old WF) and destination (new 2013 WF) workflows to a Visio 2013 diagram (.vwi file).
- Put .zip file extension on the end of each file. Open both files.
- Copy workflow.xoml.wfconfig.xml from the destination workflow to source workflow. (It is destination to source, not source to destination).
- Remove the .zip extension from the Source Workflow .vwi.zip file to reset it back to a .vwi file, and delete the "Destination" workflow file.  It will no longer be needed.
- Open the new 2013 workflow and select "Import from Visio", and select your file.  It should import your workflow just fine.

Just note that if you use this method across sites, though, any lookups to different lists will have to be reset, because list GUIDs will be different.  But on the same site, same list, you should be fine.